# Show a PHP page in drupal 7

Tags: external-scripts

I have a php script that does some querying and book keeping of drupal tables. How can I run this php script directly from the url? The script uses drupal functions so I guess it should be aware of the API.

When I go to `mysite.com/script.php` I would like this file to run...

Is there any includes that I can add and then run the script so that it is drupal aware and at the same time, does not need to go through all the view/node/block etc? Basically I do not want to add this page as a PHP block data into one of the nodes, I would like to run in directly from the URL.

Comment: Better to just wrap the PHP script as a Drupal module. Basically add a .info metadata file and put the PHP code in the .module file. More info: https://drupal.org/developing/modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should boot drupal on your file so that your file be aware of drupal functions,you can do this by :
YOUR_DRUPAL_ROOT= root of your drupal,here my drupal root was crawler.alexa.com. and 
require bootstrap.inc of your drupal.
and then boot drupal compeletly.
here is my example :

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', '../crawler.alexa.com');
require_once '../crawler.alexa.com/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would put create a module, and use [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7).

```
function mymodule_menu() {
    $items['custom/script'] = array(
      'page callback' => 'mymodule_custom_script_function',
    );
    return $items;
}

function mymodule_custom_script_function() {
    // put the code from your PHP script here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the configuration setting.

Just follow the link and you will have the solution.

https://github.com/perusio/drupal-with-nginx/issues/63